# Реализация поиска моделей Django

Tags: python, django, поиск, search, model

Не выводятся результаты поиска моделей

Сама модель, которая должна находиться:
models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name = "Заголовок")
    post = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Текст")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/blog/%Y/%m/%d', help_text='150x150px',
                              verbose_name='Ссылка картинки')
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = "Дата")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null = True, blank  = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, verbose_name = "Категория") #cjplfybt мягкой связи, когда удаление вторичного объекта не приводит к удалению первичного
    # Добвление лайков
    likes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Нравится', default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Не нравится', default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Статьи"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

вьюха от приложения "search":
views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q
from news.models import Articles


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'search/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Получаем не отфильтрованный кверисет всех моделей
        queryset = Articles.objects.all()
        q = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if q:
        # Если 'q' в GET запросе, фильтруем кверисет по данным из 'q'
            return queryset.filter(Q(title__icontains=q)| Q(post__icontains=q))
        return queryset
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
from .views import ArticleListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^article_search/', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_search'),
]
```

сама форма, которая отвечает за поиск

```
<form action="{% url 'article_search' %}" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get">

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите запрос">
                      </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
                      </form>
```

ну и сам шаблон страницы, куда должен выводиться результат:

index.html

```
{% extends "mainApp/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Поиск</h1>
    {% if article in article_lists %}
        {% for article in article_lists %}
            <article>
                <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <h2>{{ article.article_title }}</h2>
                </a>
                {{ article.post|safe }}
                <p><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">Читать далее</a></p>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>Не найдено публикаций по вашему запросу<br>Попробуйте повторить запрос с другой формулировкой</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Поиск не работает,  выдает вариант, что "не найдено публикаций...". Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В index.html условие `{% if article in article_lists %}` неверное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию `ListView` создает в шаблонах переменную `object_list`, в которую попадает вся коллекция из queryset.

**В вашем случае**, нужно в шаблоне заменить **все** переменные `article_lists` на `object_list`